# stack text in dump file dosen't record user code information

Tags: c++, qt, dump

I am developing a multi-threaded GUI program using Qt. My program needs to run 7×24 hours, but it crashes randomly. I use minidump in the program to capture exceptions, but when I analyze the dump with WinDbg, the stack text does not include my user code.
Here is the code to config minidump:

```
LONG ApplicationCrashHandler(EXCEPTION_POINTERS *pException)
{
    //create dump file
    QString fileName=QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") + ".dmp";;
    HANDLE hDumpFile = CreateFile((LPCWSTR)(fileName.toStdWString().c_str()), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hDumpFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MINIDUMP_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION dumpInfo;
        dumpInfo.ExceptionPointers = pException;
        dumpInfo.ThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
        dumpInfo.ClientPointers = TRUE;
        MiniDumpWriteDump(GetCurrentProcess(), GetCurrentProcessId(), hDumpFile, MiniDumpNormal, &dumpInfo, NULL, NULL);
    }
    QMessageBox::critical(nullptr, "error",
                          "Program crash",
                          QMessageBox::Ok,QMessageBox::NoButton);
    return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SetUtf8Code();
    MyQApplication a(argc, argv);
    QThreadPool::globalInstance()->setMaxThreadCount(20) ;
    SetUnhandledExceptionFilter((LPTOP_LEVEL_EXCEPTION_FILTER)ApplicationCrashHandler);//register exception handler
    LoadStyle();
    return a.exec();
}
```

here is stack text using in winDbg:

```
CONTEXT:  (.ecxr)
rax=0000000012aa0dc8 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=000000005ebcefe0
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=000000002133f940 rdi=000000002133f930
rip=000007fee9c3e1ec rsp=000000002133f550 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=000000002133f640 r10=0000000000000000
r11=0000000000000246 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010206
Qt5Cored!QStaticPlugin::operator=+0x4aceb:
000007fe`e9c3e1ec f0480fb111      lock cmpxchg qword ptr [rcx],rdx ds:00000000`5ebcefe0=????????????????
Resetting default scope

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 000007fee9c3e1ec (Qt5Cored!QStaticPlugin::operator=+0x000000000004aceb)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000001
   Parameter[1]: 000000005ebcefe0
Attempt to write to address 000000005ebcefe0

PROCESS_NAME:  HammerTester.exe

WRITE_ADDRESS:  000000005ebcefe0 

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - 0x%p            0x%p                    %s

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  c0000005

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000001

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  000000005ebcefe0

STACK_TEXT:  
00000000`2133f550 000007fe`e9c32a71     : 00000000`5ebcefe0 00000000`12aa0dc8 00000000`00000000 000007fe`e9c76308 : Qt5Cored!QStaticPlugin::operator=+0x4aceb
00000000`2133f570 000007fe`e9c3e31a     : 00000000`5ebcefe0 00000000`12aa0dc8 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : Qt5Cored!QStaticPlugin::operator=+0x3f570
00000000`2133f5a0 000007fe`e9c767fa     : 00000000`5ebcefe0 00000000`12aa0dc8 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : Qt5Cored!QStaticPlugin::operator=+0x4ae19
00000000`2133f5d0 000007fe`e9c76b54     : 00000000`5ebcefe0 00000000`2133f640 00000000`5ebcefe0 000007fe`e9c34073 : Qt5Cored!QStaticPlugin::operator=+0x832f9
00000000`2133f620 000007fe`e9c3f5bb     : 00000000`5ebcefe0 000007fe`e9c87d97 00000000`2133f6b0 00000000`2133f6a8 : Qt5Cored!QStaticPlugin::operator=+0x83653
00000000`2133f660 000007fe`e9c34073     : 00000000`2133f700 00000000`58afcff0 00000000`536c0fe0 ffffffff`fffffffe : Qt5Cored!QStaticPlugin::operator=+0x4c0ba
00000000`2133f6a0 000007fe`e9c7c980     : 00000000`2133f700 00000000`5ebcefe0 00000000`3c03ffe0 000007fe`eceed13a : Qt5Cored!QStaticPlugin::operator=+0x40b72
00000000`2133f6d0 000007fe`e806c2a4     : 00000000`002f43e0 00000000`00000001 00000000`000000c8 000007fe`e9c325d3 : Qt5Cored!QStaticPlugin::operator=+0x8947f
00000000`2133f720 000007fe`e806989b     : 00000000`4fef2fb8 00000000`00000000 000007fe`ecef07b0 000007fe`e9c32acb : Qt5Guid!QOpenGLFunctions_4_1_Core::glViewportIndexedf+0x1cb5e6
00000000`2133f750 000007fe`e806b20b     : 00000000`4fef2fb8 00000000`2133f830 00000000`3cc84fb0 000007fe`e9c3e364 : Qt5Guid!QOpenGLFunctions_4_1_Core::glViewportIndexedf+0x1c8bdd
00000000`2133f780 000007fe`e8069adf     : 00000000`4fef2fb8 00000000`2133f830 00000000`00000000 000007fe`e9c38442 : Qt5Guid!QOpenGLFunctions_4_1_Core::glViewportIndexedf+0x1ca54d
00000000`2133f7b0 000007fe`e806ca90     : 00000000`4fef2f00 00000000`4fef2fb8 ffffffff`fffffffe 00000000`00000001 : Qt5Guid!QOpenGLFunctions_4_1_Core::glViewportIndexedf+0x1c8e21
00000000`2133f7e0 000007fe`e9c6ca8f     : 00000000`4fef2fb0 000007fe`ea2e1508 00000000`00000001 ffffffff`fffffffe : Qt5Guid!QOpenGLFunctions_4_1_Core::glViewportIndexedf+0x1cbdd2
00000000`2133f820 000007fe`e9c6cf0a     : 00000000`4fef2fb0 00000000`3cc84fc8 ffffffff`fffffffe 000007fe`e9c76b21 : Qt5Cored!QStaticPlugin::operator=+0x7958e
00000000`2133f860 000007fe`e9c7fe1a     : 00000000`4fef2fa0 00000000`00000810 00000000`2133f920 ffffffff`fffffffe : Qt5Cored!QStaticPlugin::operator=+0x79a09
00000000`2133f890 000007fe`e9c71e88     : 00000000`3c045fd0 00000000`244b2f00 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : Qt5Cored!QStaticPlugin::operator=+0x8c919
00000000`2133f980 00000000`76f7652d     : 00000000`3c045fd0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : Qt5Cored!QStaticPlugin::operator=+0x7e987
00000000`2133fa00 00000000`770ac521     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
00000000`2133fa30 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d


SYMBOL_NAME:  Qt5Cored+4aceb

MODULE_NAME: Qt5Cored

IMAGE_NAME:  Qt5Cored.dll

STACK_COMMAND:  ~22s; .ecxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  INVALID_POINTER_WRITE_AVRF_c0000005_Qt5Cored.dll!Unknown
```

I couldn't find something useful in it.I'm also not clear about "Qt5Cored!QStaticPlugin" exactly is. Is there any suggested measure to find the root cause of the crash?

I used ~*kv to see all threads stack text, but I still can't find any useful information.

Updates 2023.10.29
I have further testd the program and got the dump analyzed. The reuslt is shown below
[image: windbg shortcut 1]
[image: windbg shortcut 2]
I think the shortcuts are show that the crash is about lock used in program. but I still don't know which is next step to find the root cause of the crash.

Comment: Well, it is not out of question that the actual crash occurs at the location indicated by the stack. For example, if you corrupt memory at some location, the crash might occur later and at a totally different location. That is how this goes unfortunately.

Comment: Do you use pointers or references to objects and pass them to threads? When designing any multithreaded application be very sure you know how long objects live. They either need to "live" longer than the threads using them. Or you can have shared_ptr's to objects and when you start a thread you can capture that shared_ptr by value in a lambda to extend the lifetime of the object for the duration of the threads lifetime. With multithreading and no design you are going to end up calling deleted objects.

Comment: Yes, I use pointers to objects in my program and use QMutex and QSharedPointer to avoid race condition, I have further test and got dump analyzed，I think it's about dead lock. I updated my question and do you have further comments? @PepijnKramer

Comment: You are right, my program crashed many times in the same postion which showed in my question according to my tests.   I updated my question,  do you have further comments? @Christian.K